# Setup a default initialization of AWS Powershell for all local users

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-powershell

I having a jump server and an RDP Manager running on it, for quick accessing the hosts in the private subnet. I need to enable every local user on that machine to start/stop the instances via a powershell script. I created an programatic user, and now I want to share these credentials amongs all local users.

In other words, I want to initialize it once with my admin user, and that everyone else load these credentials by default. Is the way via programtaic user OK, or should I do it via Role ARN?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I accomplished it with a role assigned to the host. In this way I manage the EC2 instances without the need of the credentials.